# GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed error in Opencv

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Am trying to open the web camera through GSTREAMER API using Opencv on windows, but am getting 
this error at runtime

> GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
>   OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: unable to query pipeline state

Below is code am running

```
VideoCapture capture(0,CAP_GSTREAMER);

if (capture.isOpened()) {
    std::cout << "Camera 0 via " << capture.getBackendName() << " backend" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Frame width: " << capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "     height: " << capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Capturing FPS: " << capture.get(CAP_PROP_FPS) << std::endl;
}
```

However camera is working fine with Gstreamer command

> gst-launch-1.0.exe -v ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! autovideosink

I have built OpenCV4.0 with GStreamer enabled, what exactly missing element here and is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code:

```
const char* pipeline= "ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! autovideoconvert ! appsink";

int cap_id = CAP_GSTREAMER;

VideoCapture cap( pipeline, cap_id);
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and clarify why it would help?